# A Set Theory of proving subset

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

- List item

> Let $f: X\to Y$, and set $\mathcal C$ which is not empty subsets of $X$, and a set $\mathcal D$: $$\emptyset\neq\mathcal D\subseteq\lbrace B\in\mathcal P(Y)\mid\exists A\in\mathcal C(B = f(A))\rbrace.$$ Determine whether $$\lbrace y\in Y\mid\forall A\in\mathcal C(y\in f(A))\rbrace\subseteq\bigcap\mathcal D.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m afraid that I can make no sense of your argument. The $B$ in the first displayed expression is a dummy variable that simply gives us a way to talk about certain subsets of $Y$, namely, those that are images under $f$ of members of the family $\mathscr{C}$ of subsets of $X$.

We know that for each $D\in\mathscr{D}$ there is some $A\in\mathscr{C}$ such that $D=f[A]$, so $\mathscr{D}\subseteq\{f[A]:A\in\mathscr{C}\}$. This immediately implies that

$$\bigcap\{f[A]:A\in\mathscr{C}\}\subseteq\bigcap\mathscr{D}\,.$$

> It is a general fact that if $\mathscr{G}$ and $\mathscr{H}$ are collections of sets, and $\mathscr{G}\subseteq\mathscr{H}$, then $\bigcap\mathscr{H}\subseteq\bigcap\mathscr{G}$: intersecting *more* sets cannot increase the size of the intersection. (If you’ve not seen this before, you should try to prove it. Just show that if $x\in\bigcap\mathscr{H}$, then $x\in\bigcap\mathscr{G}$.)

Finally, by definition $\{y\in Y:\forall A\in\mathscr{C}\,(y\in f[A])\}=\bigcap\{f[A]:A\in\mathscr{C}\}$, so

$$\{y\in Y:\forall A\in\mathscr{C}\,(y\in f[A])\}\subseteq\bigcap\mathscr{D}\,.$$

Comment: Thank you! I got it

Comment: @dzzhang: You’re welcome!